# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

Tags: xcode, linker-errors, arm64, armv7

When I run the Xcode without google mobile ads it build and runs perfectly fine, but after importing google mobile ads with hey zap in it, it got me this error. Please help me with this.

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>   "_GADURemoveNativeExpressAdView", referenced from:
>         _Externs_GADURemoveNativeExpressAdView_m278772814 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _NativeExpressAdClient_DestroyNativeExpressAdView_m438363790 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADURemoveNativeExpressAdView_m278772814)   "_GADUHideNativeExpressAdView", referenced from:
>         _Externs_GADUHideNativeExpressAdView_m2874361057 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _NativeExpressAdClient_HideNativeExpressAdView_m855574719 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUHideNativeExpressAdView_m2874361057)   "_GADUSetRewardBasedVideoAdCallbacks", referenced from:
>         _Externs_GADUSetRewardBasedVideoAdCallbacks_m60543576 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUSetRewardBasedVideoAdCallbacks_m60543576)   "_GADURequestInterstitial", referenced from:
>         _Externs_GADURequestInterstitial_m1951701167 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _InterstitialClient_LoadAd_m948569282 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADURequestInterstitial_m1951701167)   "_GADUShowInterstitial", referenced from:
>         _Externs_GADUShowInterstitial_m317374681 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _InterstitialClient_ShowInterstitial_m1108352439 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUShowInterstitial_m317374681)   "_GADUInterstitialReady", referenced from:
>         _Externs_GADUInterstitialReady_m3465943570 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _InterstitialClient_IsLoaded_m2546731964 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUInterstitialReady_m3465943570)   "_GADUSetInterstitialCallbacks", referenced from:
>         _Externs_GADUSetInterstitialCallbacks_m3435096038 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUSetInterstitialCallbacks_m3435096038)   "_GADUCreateInterstitial", referenced from:
>         _Externs_GADUCreateInterstitial_m379800865 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _InterstitialClient_CreateInterstitialAd_m2712832591 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUCreateInterstitial_m379800865)   "_GADUShowRewardBasedVideoAd", referenced from:
>         _Externs_GADUShowRewardBasedVideoAd_m3062097867 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _RewardBasedVideoAdClient_ShowRewardBasedVideoAd_m3845420349 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUShowRewardBasedVideoAd_m3062097867)   "_GADUSetExtra", referenced from:
>         _Externs_GADUSetExtra_m3623374276 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUSetExtra_m3623374276)   "_GADUCreateRewardBasedVideoAd", referenced from:
>         _Externs_GADUCreateRewardBasedVideoAd_m2416696805 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _RewardBasedVideoAdClient_CreateRewardBasedVideoAd_m1062641236 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUCreateRewardBasedVideoAd_m2416696805)   "_GADUAddTestDevice", referenced from:
>         _Externs_GADUAddTestDevice_m2619105564 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUAddTestDevice_m2619105564)   "_GADUCreateRequest", referenced from:
>         _Externs_GADUCreateRequest_m3767898388 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUCreateRequest_m3767898388)   "_GADUSetRequestAgent", referenced from:
>         _Externs_GADUSetRequestAgent_m1681430595 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUSetRequestAgent_m1681430595)   "_GADUNativeCustomTemplateAdPerformClickOnAssetWithKey", referenced
>   from:
>         _CustomNativeTemplateClient_PerformClick_m2155707301 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _Externs_GADUNativeCustomTemplateAdPerformClickOnAssetWithKey_m2056793025
>   in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUNativeCustomTemplateAdPerformClickOnAssetWithKey_m2056793025)
>   "_GADURequestRewardBasedVideoAd", referenced from:
>         _Externs_GADURequestRewardBasedVideoAd_m1364215841 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _RewardBasedVideoAdClient_LoadAd_m483440913 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADURequestRewardBasedVideoAd_m1364215841)   "_GADUNativeCustomTemplateAdImageAsBytesForKey", referenced from:
>         _Externs_GADUNativeCustomTemplateAdImageAsBytesForKey_m3469983901 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUNativeCustomTemplateAdImageAsBytesForKey_m3469983901)   "_GADUSetNativeExpressAdCallbacks", referenced from:
>         _Externs_GADUSetNativeExpressAdCallbacks_m670381706 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUSetNativeExpressAdCallbacks_m670381706)   "_GADUNativeCustomTemplateAdAvailableAssetKeys", referenced from:
>         _CustomNativeTemplateClient_GetAvailableAssetNames_m2390231515 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _Externs_GADUNativeCustomTemplateAdAvailableAssetKeys_m2356950897 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUNativeCustomTemplateAdAvailableAssetKeys_m2356950897)   "_GADUNativeCustomTemplateAdNumberOfAvailableAssetKeys", referenced
>   from:
>         _CustomNativeTemplateClient_GetAvailableAssetNames_m2390231515 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _Externs_GADUNativeCustomTemplateAdNumberOfAvailableAssetKeys_m1052451184
>   in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUNativeCustomTemplateAdNumberOfAvailableAssetKeys_m1052451184)
>   "_GADUSetBannerCallbacks", referenced from:
>         _Externs_GADUSetBannerCallbacks_m3729149127 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUSetBannerCallbacks_m3729149127)   "_GADURemoveBannerView", referenced from:
>         _BannerClient_DestroyBannerView_m370805023 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _Externs_GADURemoveBannerView_m1043062268 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADURemoveBannerView_m1043062268)   "_GADUCreateSmartBannerView", referenced from:
>         _BannerClient_CreateBannerView_m3151825253 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _Externs_GADUCreateSmartBannerView_m3209579712 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUCreateSmartBannerView_m3209579712)   "_GADUSetNativeCustomTemplateAdUnityClient", referenced from:
>         _CustomNativeTemplateClient__ctor_m185162473 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _Externs_GADUSetNativeCustomTemplateAdUnityClient_m2417165562 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUSetNativeCustomTemplateAdUnityClient_m2417165562)   "_hz_ads_incentivized_is_available", referenced from:
>         _HZIncentivizedAd_IsAvailable_m1540921192 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZIncentivizedAdIOS_IsAvailable_m2890366693 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZIncentivizedAdIOS_hz_ads_incentivized_is_available_m3313022680 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HZIncentivizedAdIOS_hz_ads_incentivized_is_available_m3313022680)   "_GADUCreateAdLoader", referenced from:
>         _Externs_GADUCreateAdLoader_m2102964107 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUCreateAdLoader_m2102964107)   "_hz_show_chartboost_for_location", referenced from:
>         _HZInterstitialAd_ChartboostShowForLocation_m3986856550 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZInterstitialAdIOS_chartboostShowForLocation_m3526786300 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZInterstitialAd_chartboostShowForLocation_m3031668999 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZInterstitialAdIOS_hz_show_chartboost_for_location_m507508069 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HZInterstitialAdIOS_hz_show_chartboost_for_location_m507508069)   "_hz_chartboost_is_available_for_location", referenced from:
>         _HZInterstitialAd_ChartboostIsAvailableForLocation_m3620865240 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZInterstitialAdIOS_chartboostIsAvailableForLocation_m1841100776 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZInterstitialAd_chartboostIsAvailableForLocation_m1017882628 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZInterstitialAdIOS_hz_chartboost_is_available_for_location_m2546445187
>   in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HZInterstitialAdIOS_hz_chartboost_is_available_for_location_m2546445187)
>   "_GADUSetBirthday", referenced from:
>         _Externs_GADUSetBirthday_m705684977 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUSetBirthday_m705684977)   "_hz_fetch_chartboost_for_location", referenced from:
>         _HZInterstitialAd_ChartboostFetchForLocation_m2174698268 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZInterstitialAdIOS_chartboostFetchForLocation_m3429167094 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZInterstitialAd_chartboostFetchForLocation_m2193778388 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZInterstitialAdIOS_hz_fetch_chartboost_for_location_m1446482892 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HZInterstitialAdIOS_hz_fetch_chartboost_for_location_m1446482892)   "_hz_ads_interstitial_is_available", referenced from:
>         _HZInterstitialAd_IsAvailable_m1603813371 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZInterstitialAdIOS_IsAvailable_m345148048 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZInterstitialAdIOS_hz_ads_interstitial_is_available_m1839793194 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HZInterstitialAdIOS_hz_ads_interstitial_is_available_m1839793194)   "_GADUHideBannerView", referenced from:
>         _BannerClient_HideBannerView_m981181952 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _Externs_GADUHideBannerView_m2190757742 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUHideBannerView_m2190757742)   "_hz_ads_show_video", referenced from:
>         _HZVideoAdIOS_ShowWithOptions_m3493183518 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZVideoAdIOS_hz_ads_show_video_m91336940 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HZVideoAdIOS_hz_ads_show_video_m91336940)   "_hz_ads_fetch_interstitial", referenced from:
>         _HZInterstitialAd_Fetch_m2382367409 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZInterstitialAdIOS_Fetch_m2985378400 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZInterstitialAdIOS_hz_ads_fetch_interstitial_m2332423193 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HZInterstitialAdIOS_hz_ads_fetch_interstitial_m2332423193)   "_hz_demo_set_birth_date", referenced from:
>         _HeyzapDemographicsIOS_hz_demo_set_birth_date_m2786526817 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapDemographicsIOS_SetUserBirthDate_m2058992474 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZDemographics_SetUserBirthDate_m91290354 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HeyzapDemographicsIOS_hz_demo_set_birth_date_m2786526817)   "_GADUShowBannerView", referenced from:
>         _BannerClient_ShowBannerView_m3342074583 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _Externs_GADUShowBannerView_m3079181443 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUShowBannerView_m3079181443)   "_GADURequestBannerAd", referenced from:
>         _BannerClient_LoadAd_m951389674 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _Externs_GADURequestBannerAd_m2043695255 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADURequestBannerAd_m2043695255)   "_hz_demo_set_household_income", referenced from:
>         _HeyzapDemographicsIOS_hz_demo_set_household_income_m3000447652 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapDemographicsIOS_SetUserHouseholdIncome_m4125848763 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZDemographics_SetUserHouseholdIncome_m2271484631 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HeyzapDemographicsIOS_hz_demo_set_household_income_m3000447652)   "_hz_ads_hide_banner", referenced from:
>         _HZBannerAd_Hide_m3106653491 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZBannerAdIOS_Hide_m2253841562 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZBannerAd_hide_m3171665203 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZBannerAdIOS_hz_ads_hide_banner_m4111709803 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HZBannerAdIOS_hz_ads_hide_banner_m4111709803)   "_hz_demo_set_location", referenced from:
>         _HeyzapDemographicsIOS_hz_demo_set_location_m4229425369 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapDemographicsIOS_SetUserLocation_m502496043 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZDemographics_SetUserLocation_m2036763895 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HeyzapDemographicsIOS_hz_demo_set_location_m4229425369)   "_hz_ads_banner_dimensions", referenced from:
>         _HZBannerAdIOS_GetCurrentBannerDimensions_m2953804792 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZBannerAdIOS_hz_ads_banner_dimensions_m249523435 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HZBannerAdIOS_hz_ads_banner_dimensions_m249523435)   "_GADUCreateBannerView", referenced from:
>         _BannerClient_CreateBannerView_m3151825253 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _Externs_GADUCreateBannerView_m637407593 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUCreateBannerView_m637407593)   "_hz_demo_set_education_level", referenced from:
>         _HeyzapDemographicsIOS_hz_demo_set_education_level_m1074538939 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapDemographicsIOS_SetUserEducationLevel_m4213421947 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZDemographics_SetUserEducationLevel_m3447840272 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HeyzapDemographicsIOS_hz_demo_set_education_level_m1074538939)   "_GADUSetNativeCustomTemplateAdCallbacks", referenced from:
>         _CustomNativeTemplateClient__ctor_m185162473 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _Externs_GADUSetNativeCustomTemplateAdCallbacks_m1125841482 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUSetNativeCustomTemplateAdCallbacks_m1125841482)   "_GADUAddKeyword", referenced from:
>         _Externs_GADUAddKeyword_m170650300 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUAddKeyword_m170650300)   "_hz_demo_set_marital_status", referenced from:
>         _HeyzapDemographicsIOS_hz_demo_set_marital_status_m4264265156 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapDemographicsIOS_SetUserMaritalStatus_m2336201332 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZDemographics_SetUserMaritalStatus_m2114548606 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HeyzapDemographicsIOS_hz_demo_set_marital_status_m4264265156)   "_hz_ads_show_banner", referenced from:
>         _HZBannerAdIOS_hz_ads_show_banner_m844562234 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HZBannerAdIOS_hz_ads_show_banner_m844562234)   "_GADUSetGender", referenced from:
>         _Externs_GADUSetGender_m1672314204 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUSetGender_m1672314204)   "_hz_ads_video_is_available", referenced from:
>         _HZVideoAd_IsAvailable_m1112100759 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZVideoAdIOS_IsAvailable_m566392985 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZVideoAdIOS_hz_ads_video_is_available_m2802537609 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HZVideoAdIOS_hz_ads_video_is_available_m2802537609)   "_hz_ads_destroy_banner", referenced from:
>         _HZBannerAd_Destroy_m1123231298 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZBannerAdIOS_Destroy_m2858549805 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZBannerAd_destroy_m3272812099 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZBannerAdIOS_hz_ads_destroy_banner_m3248294314 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HZBannerAdIOS_hz_ads_destroy_banner_m3248294314)   "_hz_ads_fetch_video", referenced from:
>         _HZVideoAd_Fetch_m3003327403 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZVideoAdIOS_Fetch_m2640243129 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZVideoAdIOS_hz_ads_fetch_video_m2402929377 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HZVideoAdIOS_hz_ads_fetch_video_m2402929377)   "_hz_ads_show_incentivized_with_custom_info", referenced from:
>         _HZIncentivizedAdIOS_hz_ads_show_incentivized_with_custom_info_m1007578503
>   in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HZIncentivizedAdIOS_hz_ads_show_incentivized_with_custom_info_m1007578503)
>   "_GADURequestNativeExpressAd", referenced from:
>         _Externs_GADURequestNativeExpressAd_m1530144587 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _NativeExpressAdClient_LoadAd_m689647354 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADURequestNativeExpressAd_m1530144587)   "_hz_demo_set_postal_code", referenced from:
>         _HeyzapDemographicsIOS_hz_demo_set_postal_code_m3524253889 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapDemographicsIOS_SetUserPostalCode_m790782740 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZDemographics_SetUserPostalCode_m3952519016 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HeyzapDemographicsIOS_hz_demo_set_postal_code_m3524253889)   "_hz_add_facebook_test_device", referenced from:
>         _HeyzapAds_AddFacebookTestDevice_m2614526347 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapAdsIOS_AddFacebookTestDevice_m3071736259 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapAdsIOS_hz_add_facebook_test_device_m3268066733 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HeyzapAdsIOS_hz_add_facebook_test_device_m3268066733)   "_GADUSetAdLoaderCallbacks", referenced from:
>         _AdLoaderClient__ctor_m1557270517 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _Externs_GADUSetAdLoaderCallbacks_m2055661077 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUSetAdLoaderCallbacks_m2055661077)   "_hz_ads_hide_debug_logs", referenced from:
>         _HeyzapAds_HideDebugLogs_m607353008 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapAdsIOS_HideDebugLogs_m3900745262 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapAdsIOS_hz_ads_hide_debug_logs_m3235983610 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HeyzapAdsIOS_hz_ads_hide_debug_logs_m3235983610)   "_GADURewardBasedVideoAdReady", referenced from:
>         _Externs_GADURewardBasedVideoAdReady_m4207898111 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _RewardBasedVideoAdClient_IsLoaded_m2548387472 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADURewardBasedVideoAdReady_m4207898111)   "_hz_ads_set_bundle_identifier", referenced from:
>         _HeyzapAds_SetBundleIdentifier_m422072036 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapAdsIOS_SetBundleIdentifier_m964202891 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapAdsIOS_hz_ads_set_bundle_identifier_m1167716683 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HeyzapAdsIOS_hz_ads_set_bundle_identifier_m1167716683)   "_hz_demo_set_gender", referenced from:
>         _HeyzapDemographicsIOS_hz_demo_set_gender_m3921170503 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapDemographicsIOS_SetUserGender_m858252892 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZDemographics_SetUserGender_m1656353232 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HeyzapDemographicsIOS_hz_demo_set_gender_m3921170503)   "_GADUNativeCustomTemplateAdStringForKey", referenced from:
>         _Externs_GADUNativeCustomTemplateAdStringForKey_m1814981821 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUNativeCustomTemplateAdStringForKey_m1814981821)   "_hz_ads_hide_third_party_debug_logs", referenced from:
>         _HeyzapAds_HideThirdPartyDebugLogs_m1197142779 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapAdsIOS_HideThirdPartyDebugLogs_m2544668192 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapAdsIOS_hz_ads_hide_third_party_debug_logs_m4103321855 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HeyzapAdsIOS_hz_ads_hide_third_party_debug_logs_m4103321855)   "_hz_ads_show_mediation_debug_view_controller", referenced from:
>         _HeyzapAds_ShowMediationTestSuite_m3622266385 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapAdsIOS_ShowMediationTestSuite_m2784503268 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapAdsIOS_hz_ads_show_mediation_debug_view_controller_m66858472 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HeyzapAdsIOS_hz_ads_show_mediation_debug_view_controller_m66858472)   "_GADUCreateNativeExpressAdView", referenced from:
>         _Externs_GADUCreateNativeExpressAdView_m1189577116 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _NativeExpressAdClient_CreateNativeExpressAdView_m3228391842 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUCreateNativeExpressAdView_m1189577116)   "_GADUNativeCustomTemplateAdRecordImpression", referenced from:
>         _CustomNativeTemplateClient_RecordImpression_m2791723233 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _Externs_GADUNativeCustomTemplateAdRecordImpression_m2830668986 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUNativeCustomTemplateAdRecordImpression_m2830668986)   "_GADURelease", referenced from:
>         _AdLoaderClient__ctor_m1557270517 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _AdLoaderClient_set_AdLoaderPtr_m1465180173 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _Externs_GADURelease_m763974323 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _AdLoaderClient_LoadAd_m3859723484 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _AdLoaderClient_DestroyAdLoader_m825051728 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _BannerClient_set_BannerViewPtr_m702970481 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _BannerClient_CreateBannerView_m3151825253 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         ...
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADURelease_m763974323)   "_hz_ads_fetch_incentivized", referenced from:
>         _HZIncentivizedAd_Fetch_m2216191418 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZIncentivizedAdIOS_Fetch_m2500953001 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZIncentivizedAdIOS_hz_ads_fetch_incentivized_m4124814398 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HZIncentivizedAdIOS_hz_ads_fetch_incentivized_m4124814398)   "_hz_ads_show_debug_logs", referenced from:
>         _HeyzapAds_ShowDebugLogs_m3572153114 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapAdsIOS_ShowDebugLogs_m2038353020 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapAdsIOS_hz_ads_show_debug_logs_m1193843236 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HeyzapAdsIOS_hz_ads_show_debug_logs_m1193843236)   "_GADURequestNativeAd", referenced from:
>         _AdLoaderClient_LoadAd_m3859723484 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _Externs_GADURequestNativeAd_m3836341943 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADURequestNativeAd_m3836341943)   "_hz_ads_show_interstitial", referenced from:
>         _HZInterstitialAdIOS_ShowWithOptions_m240929845 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HZInterstitialAdIOS_hz_ads_show_interstitial_m3204134323 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HZInterstitialAdIOS_hz_ads_show_interstitial_m3204134323)   "_hz_resume_expensive_work", referenced from:
>         _HeyzapAds_ResumeExpensiveWork_m2844433033 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapAdsIOS_ResumeExpensiveWork_m842565167 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapAdsIOS_hz_resume_expensive_work_m3009083240 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HeyzapAdsIOS_hz_resume_expensive_work_m3009083240)   "_hz_ads_is_network_initialized", referenced from:
>         _HeyzapAds_IsNetworkInitialized_m4113149350 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapAdsIOS_IsNetworkInitialized_m3893144594 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapAdsIOS_hz_ads_is_network_initialized_m21054957 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HeyzapAdsIOS_hz_ads_is_network_initialized_m21054957)   "_GADUShowNativeExpressAdView", referenced from:
>         _Externs_GADUShowNativeExpressAdView_m3313793310 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _NativeExpressAdClient_ShowNativeExpressAdView_m1541731140 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUShowNativeExpressAdView_m3313793310)   "_GADUTagForChildDirectedTreatment", referenced from:
>         _Externs_GADUTagForChildDirectedTreatment_m1380093157 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUTagForChildDirectedTreatment_m1380093157)   "_GADUNativeCustomTemplateAdTemplateID", referenced from:
>         _CustomNativeTemplateClient_GetTemplateId_m1500792757 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>         _Externs_GADUNativeCustomTemplateAdTemplateID_m684542946 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUNativeCustomTemplateAdTemplateID_m684542946)   "_hz_ads_show_third_party_debug_logs", referenced from:
>         _HeyzapAds_ShowThirdPartyDebugLogs_m2986980698 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapAdsIOS_ShowThirdPartyDebugLogs_m4239785028 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapAdsIOS_hz_ads_show_third_party_debug_logs_m3067452701 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HeyzapAdsIOS_hz_ads_show_third_party_debug_logs_m3067452701)   "_hz_ads_start_app", referenced from:
>         _HeyzapAds_Start_m230113188 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapAdsIOS_Start_m721179842 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapAdsIOS_hz_ads_start_app_m4119560161 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HeyzapAdsIOS_hz_ads_start_app_m4119560161)   "_hz_pause_expensive_work", referenced from:
>         _HeyzapAds_PauseExpensiveWork_m4078407665 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapAdsIOS_PauseExpensiveWork_m2310303354 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapAdsIOS_hz_pause_expensive_work_m4057608835 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HeyzapAdsIOS_hz_pause_expensive_work_m4057608835)   "_hz_ads_get_remote_data", referenced from:
>         _HeyzapAds_GetRemoteData_m2088934164 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapAdsIOS_GetRemoteData_m3138596738 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _HeyzapAdsIOS_hz_ads_get_remote_data_m1436901786 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _HeyzapAdsIOS_hz_ads_get_remote_data_m1436901786) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 clang:
>
> error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Fatemeh Abdollahei: i am getting this error when i run the Xcode with google mobile ads with heyzap in it, i tested and run the Xcode without the google mobile ads and it runs perfectly in the iPhone but after importing the ads in it, the above errors comes up. I tried everything every comment from stack overflow and more sites, but i can't resolving this issue. Please see it and help me with it.

Comment: Why is this tagged `[arm64]`?

Comment: @Siguza it is tagged because when i select arm64 and armv7 for the architecture in build settings it got me this error: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:              while if i select only armv7 it gives me the above mentioned error